# Jetpack foam party won't work

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I have been using the bubble gum jet pack for more than long enough, but it won't acknowledge the foam party achievement.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem; I could fly as many kilometres as I want in total but the achievement was never awarded — I only eventually received it when I flew 10km with the bubble gun jet pack *in a single game*.

I had the game installed previously something like four or five years ago and am pretty sure I received every achievement then available but never got anywhere near a 10km run. So I think possibly the requirement has changed without the text being clarified, whether intentionally or not.